# RESTful API static collections

Tags: web-services, rest

I'd like to know whether 'static collections' are okay in REST.
afaik, the only allowed static collections (GET on collection that doesn't come before GET for specific object) is root, i.e.

> In the following examples 'books' is static collection but it's in root:
>   GET: api/books/ # book collection
>   GET: api/books/book_id # specific book data
>   GET: api/books/book_id/available_in_stores # stores collection for specific
>   Is the following is okay according to RESTful standarts:
>   GET: api/books/book_types
>   GET: api/books/book_types/book_type1
>   'book_types' here is a collection but it's static and can be in root as well. but logically it resides under books.

The reason for putting it there is because I don't want to overload root.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify where you picked up that "static collections" at a non-root URL would be unRESTful?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there isn't anything un-RESTful about that, if only since you might want to add versioning or a base path in the URL (as you have already with `api/` bit in your example!). From an HTTP point of view the URL structure is totally irrelevant.

However, for *caching* reasons you should make sure not to *replicate* the static resources into all your individual books, in your example under `api/books/<book_id>/book_types`, since then you'd implicitly create many instances of the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) do you know about a reference to sth that states it's not 'un-RESTful'

Comment: @gilad.chap The most important concepts to understand and to apply are "[safe and idempotent methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1)".

Comment: Good URI design are just a consequence of these concepts and of the definition of a URI (an identifier of a "resource" which could be anything). A simple rule of thumb could be "Can I send the URI by e-mail? What does it identify? Are there ways to represent it?"